# About GDI Objects

Tags: visual-c++

What's the upper limit on GDI Objects for one process in Windows 7?

I had read many articles and came to know that 10k is hard limit.

I tried all work around but not succeeded to increase GDI Objects limit. Is there any hot fix available for this? Please suggest any work around.

Comment: What types of GDI objects do you use the most?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that GDI will allow you to configure that.

In any case that should be solved other way. Usually such large numbers simply mean that redesign is needed.